# How to functionally handle a logging side effect

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I want to log in the event that a record doesn't have an adjoining record. Is there a purely functional way to do this? One that separates the side effect from the data transformation?

Here's an example of what I need to do:

```
val records: Seq[Record] = Seq(record1, record2, ...)

val accountsMap: Map[Long, Account] = Map(record1.id -> account1, ...)

def withAccount(accountsMap: Map[Long, Account])(r: Record): (Record, Option[Account]) = {
  (r, accountsMap.get(r.id))
}

def handleNoAccounts(tuple: (Record, Option[Account]) = {
  val (r, a) = tuple
  if (a.isEmpty) logger.error(s"no account for ${record.id}")
  tuple
}

def toRichAccount(tuple: (Record, Option[Account]) = {
  val (r, a) = tuple
  a.map(acct => RichAccount(r, acct))
}

records
.map(withAccount(accountsMap))
.map(handleNoAccounts) // if no account is found, log
.flatMap(toRichAccount)
```

So there are multiple issues with this approach that I think make it less than optimal.

The tuple return type is clumsy. I have to destructure the tuple in both of the latter two functions.

The logging function has to handle the logging and then return the tuple with no changes. It feels weird that this is passed to .map even though no transformation is taking place -- maybe there is a better way to get this side effect.

Is there a functional way to clean this up?

Comment: Approaches mentioned in the answers section are fine. I just want to add one more thing: logging is inherently a side-effectful thing. You are right when you say that mapping when no transformation is taking place feels weird (btw for situations like that, you can use `foreach` instead), because it *is* weird. Logging can always fail, and you're not capturing that effect. Function signature should be something like `(Record, Option[Account]) => Future[(Record, Option[Account])]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using scala 2.13 or newer you could use [tapEach](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#tapEach%5BU%5D(f:A=%3EU):C), which takes function `A => Unit` to apply side effect on every element of function and then passes collection unchanged:

```
//you no longer need to return tuple in side-effecting function
def handleNoAccounts(tuple: (Record, Option[Account]): Unit = {
  val (r, a) = tuple
  if (a.isEmpty) logger.error(s"no account for ${record.id}")
}

records
.map(withAccount(accountsMap))
.tapEach(handleNoAccounts) // if no account is found, log
.flatMap(toRichAccount)
```

In case you're using older Scala, you could provide extension method (updated according to Levi's Ramsey suggestion):

```
implicit class SeqOps[A](s: Seq[A]) {
  def tapEach(f: A => Unit): Seq[A] = {
      s.foreach(f)
      s
  }
}
```

Comment: I would think that `def tapEach(f: A => Unit): Seq[A] = { s.foreach(f); s }` would be more efficient (saving the construction of a new collection and also of a closure)

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong (I often am) but I think this does everything that's required.

```
records
  .flatMap(r => 
    accountsMap.get(r.id).fold{
      logger.error(s"no account for ${r.id}")
      Option.empty[RichAccount]
    }{a => Some(RichAccount(r,a))})
```

Comment: No that's good, the ability to call fold on an Option was unknown to me